# If $X \sim Exp(1)$ and $Y \sim Exp(1)$, prove $(\frac{X}{Y}, Y)$ is continuos without using the change of variables theorem.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, conditional-expectation

I've been thinking about this problem for a while and I'm not sure which way to go.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables with exponential distribution of parameter 1. Let $U = \frac{X}{Y}$. Without using the change of variables theorem, prove that the vector $(U,Y)$ is continuous.

I imagine this involved calculating the conditional expected value or something or other but I'm not really sure which result would imply continuousness.

Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In full generality, if $(X,Y)$ has PDF $f$ then $(U,V)=(X/Y,Y)$ has PDF $g$, with $$g(u,v)=|v|\,f(uv,v).$$

Comment: Isn't that basically the same as calculating the vector's distribution? Thanks for replying.

Comment: The fact that the PDF of (U,V) exists is guaranteed by the theorem I recalled, which does not require to know the PDF of (X,Y). Conditional expected value is not involved hence, seeing your insistence on it, one would expect some explanation why you think it is.

Comment: This problem was in the section for conditional expectation and to use that was the "hint" I was given when I asked. The correct wording of the problem actually is "without using the change of variable theorem", sorry about that. I've been working on it and I imagine the idea is to use the fact that $P(X/Y \leq t) = E (1\{X/Y \leq t\}) = E( E(1\{ X/Y \leq t\} | Y) ) $. Thanks for your comment and sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Indeed this is called omitting crucial parts of the exercise... But anyway, the link of the approach you describe with the distribution of (U,V) would be?

Comment: This is the best I've got right now. $P(\frac{X}{Y} \leq z) = E ( \int  1\{\frac{X}{Y}\leq z\}f_{\frac{X}{Y}|Y=y}(z)dy )$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent $f_{\frac{X}{Y}|Y=y}(z) = f_{X}(yz) $ so $P(\frac{X}{Y} \leq z) = \int_{R_x} \int_{R_y} f_{X}(yz) 1 \{ \frac{X}{Y} \leq z \} dy dx $. I'm not really sure this is right, but I haven't been able to come up with something that makes more sense.

Comment: The first formula in your comment seems to assume that $Y$ has PDF $1$ on $\mathbb R$ (not true). The conditional PDF after that is incorrect (does not integrate to $1$). And the rôle of $x$ in the last formula is unclear as well (makes it absurd). Sorry...

Comment: Forgive me, this problem is kinda driving me crazy. It's supposed to be rather straight forward but I see no real way of getting there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No need to go crazy, the message should have gotten through now, that using conditional distributions to solve the present question is at best a détour. On the other hand, applying general theorems as in my first comment yields the result in one line. Case closed?

Comment: I'm still not sure what the detour that can provide the solution without using the change of variables theorem would be, but I'm giving up on finding it. Again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main tool is the "change of variable" theorem which states that if $X$ is continuous with pdf $f_X$, and $g$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism, then $Y:=g(X)$ is continuous with pdf $f_Y(x) := f_X(g^{-1}(x))(g^{-1})'(x)$.

This theorem has two parts : continuity+pdf. But anyway, you only need to check that your transformation is $C^1$, bijective with reciprocal function $C^1$.

Comment: I get that, but the problem says that the change of variable theorem is not needed for this. Because of the context the problem is in I would imagine there's a solution involving conditional expectation but I haven't been able to figure it out at all.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: Well, i don't know why you are focusing on the conditional expectation, it seems to me kind of off topic.

Comment: This problem was in the section for conditional expectation and to use that was the "hint" I was given when I asked. The correct wording of the problem actually is "without using the change of variable theorem", sorry about that. I've been working on it and I imagine the idea is to use the fact that $P(X/Y \leq t) = E (1\{X/Y \leq t\}) = E( E(1\{ X/Y \leq t\} | Y) ) $ but haven't gotten much further. Thanks for your comment and sorry for being unclear.